# How to use NTLM Authentication using ghql in R

Tags: r, graphql, ntlm-authentication

Hi I'm trying to connect to my `Graphql` controller that authenticates through `ntlm` using an R script and the `ghql` library. The trouble I'm having is the only authorization examples I've found use tokens like so.

```
token <- Sys.getenv("GITHUB_GRAPHQL_TOKEN")
con <- GraphqlClient$new(
    url = "https://api.github.com/graphql",
          headers = list(Authorization = paste0("Bearer ", token))
)
```

But I need to use `ntlm` credentials. Has anyone run across a way to use `ntlm` credentials when setting up the GraphqlClient?